# Controllers are best at parsing inputs, but could I process it in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, model, controller, textfield

In my calendar application the date is stored as a text_field

```
  = text_field :task_time, :day, :value => display_date(@date), :id => "date-n"
```

I read this date in the controller's index method but then am pre-generating default time as today in the model:

```
private

   def generate_task_time

   self.task_time = Time.now if self.task_time.nil?

   end
```

I need to change it and set default task_time to the time currently displayed in the calendar, but am getting undefined local variable or method `params' error when trying to read it in the model: convert_to_string(params[:task_time]

Is it possible to do it in the model at all or is it better to remove generate_task_time and do everything in the controller?

Any suggestion on the syntax -

```
DateTime.strptime("#{params[:date]}")
```

or

```
convert_to_string(params[:task_time]) unless params[:task_time].nil?
```

Comment: Regarding your syntax, you don't need to interpolate `params[:date]` in that line. You can simply pass the value to the method: `DateTime.strptime(params[:date])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is an instance method on the controller, so you won't have access to it in the model. You can pass the value of `params[:task_time]` to the model, though:

```
task.task_time = convert_to_string(params[:task_time]) if params[:task_time]
```

It's perfectly valid to set attributes on the model from the controller. This is a common Rails pattern for updating the model attributes in a controller action:

```
if model.update_attributes(params[:model])
  # do something success-y
else
  # do something fail-y
end
```

But if you start doing too much in the controller, you get tied up with the request lifecycle and have a hard time testing your actual business logic. It's always about balance!